# Checking for null/undefined for mongoose document not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using Mongoose to search for a user in a MongoDB database inside of a loop but having a problem where if a user is NOT found (is null/undefined) my code is not breaking out of the loop and preventing the code from running if the user is not found.

I have purposely used an old hardcoded user id string of a user that doesn't exist to test the code but when I check if it is null/undefined (which it always will be) my code
**if (!user) { break }** does not recognize that the **user** is undefined/null and does not break out of the loop??

I have also tried the following checks for null/undefined but they do not work??

```
if (user._id == null) { break }
if (user == null) { break }
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
 for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    try {
      // searching for hardcoded user._id that does not exist
      const _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("63486891b3885d19f115a6e1")
      const user = await User.findOne({ _id }) 

      if (!user) { 
        console.log("Break 1") // Does not log?!
        break
      }

      // EXECUTE MORE CODE IF USER IS FOUND

    } catch (err) {
      console.log( err.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also log the result of the const user = await User.findOne({ _id }) and post it in the question?